# Efficient 2D array processing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, parallel-processing

Let `A` be a 2D matrix of size `NxL`. Every row `A[i]` should be processed independently such that all entries in consecutive chunks of length `C` in every row are replaced by the average value of the entries in the chunk. Specifically, I am looking for an efficient way to replace every `k-th` chunk in every `i-th` row `A[i][kC:(k+1)C]` by `mean(A[i][kC:(k+1)C]) * ones(length=C)`.

**Example**

`A=[[1,3,5,7], [7,5,3,1]]` should be transformed to `A=[[2,2,6,6],[6,6,2,2]]` if `C=2`.

Comment: Will axis 1 be always divisible by C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape the data into chunks, take the mean and use broadcasting to assign the data back into the array

```
 B = A.reshape(-1, C)
 B[...] = B.mean(-1)[:, None]
```

Afterwards `A` contains the desired result as `B` is not a copy but a view.

Comment: Elegant solution :) But unfortunately, wouldn't work if `A.shape[1]%0 != 0`. Not sure if this is a requirement of OP but just pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

### If a.shape[1]%c==0

```
res = np.concatenate([np.repeat(a.mean(axis=1,keepdims=True),c, axis=1) for a in np.split(A, c, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

### Else

```
res = np.concatenate(
    [np.repeat(a.mean(axis=1,keepdims=True),a.shape[1], axis=1) for a in np.split(A, list(range(0,A.shape[1],c)), axis=1)], axis=1)
```